# How to use objects to make a chatbot that can send messages based on your response?

Tags: javascript, object, bots, chat

I'm trying to make a simple chatbot in JavaScript that can send messages based on the user's input through an input field. How can I make it so the bot moves the conversation to the next index if it recognizes any of the options as correct input?

```
BOT: Hello! 
BOT: How are you feeling today? 
ME: Im feeling good.
BOT: Happy to hear that!
BOT: If you want to hear a joke say JOKE.
ME: JOKE
BOT: Two guys stole a calendar. They got six months each.
```

This is what I've got so far. I have been stuck on this for quite a while, so any help would be appreciated!

```
const story1 = {
    messages: ["Hello!", "How are you feeling today?"],
    options: { 
      "good": 2, // Check if this word is in a sentence
      "bad": 3 // Index of story
    }
}

const story2 = {
    messages: ["Happy to hear that!", "If you want to hear a joke say JOKE."],
    options: {
      "JOKE": 4
    }
}

const story3 = {
    messages: ["Sorry to hear that!", "Do you want a hug?"],
    options: {
      "yes": 5,
      "no": 6
    }
}

const story4 = {
    messages: ["Two guys stole a calendar. They got six months each."],
    options: {
      "haha": 7 // Etc...
    }
}

const step = 0;

const stories = [
    story1,
    story2,
    story3,
    story4
    ...
]
```

Comment: It look like you're off to a good start. If you use a `while (true) {}` loop, you can continually process user input until you reach some  condition. You can exit using `break`. I'm going to flag this question as vague because it's very open ended, but come back if you have a specific problem you run into. Also use let instead of const for step.

Comment: I would advise to give each story an id. Then, if an answer matches an option you know what new story id to search for in the array of stories. Then that story will become the new current story.